# Is this an Android context leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

Here's a piece of simplified code:

```
static Activity longLivedField;

onCreate(...) {     
    longLivedField = this;  // the only write to this field
}
```

I've seen people claiming this as a context leak, and create fixes for it. The typical fix is to nullify the field at appropriate places. For example, in `onPause()`:

```
onPause() {
    longLivedField = null;
}
```

Comment: Are you doing this to keep context?

Comment: Yes. And there are suggestions saying we should not do this, but use the getApplicationContext() instead. But I just want to understand why doing this could be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a memory leak if you don't nullify the field in onPause(). You almost certainly never want to retain a static reference to any Activity. What is it that you are trying to achieve?

The Android developer web site contains a handy page describing how to avoid memory leaks like this one:

[Avoiding Memory Leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Comment: I did read that post before, several times. The difference, though, is that the static field is only written to once in that example. But in this one, the static field would be written to every time a new activity object is created (well, when onCreate() is called actually), and thus the old one (the one that is supposed to be *leaked) is no longer reachable from the static field. So it seems that it can only be leaking for a short period of time, which, roughly speaking, is between onPause() and the assignment in onCreate().

Comment: That is true, but the leak will occur when the user moves to a different activity. The static field will then point to the last instance of your activity and thus leak.

Comment: Here's my understanding based on your answers, and correct me if I'm wrong: the goal is to make it possible to garbage collect the last instance of activity when the user moves to a different activity. It is important to do so because the whole GUI hierarchy of one activity (I want to say this explicitly because leaks in multiple activities or even multiple apps are obviously harmful) could consume a fairly substantial amount of memory. It is reasonable to do so because the garbage collection and object allocation are efficient enough to collect and allocate the GUI hierarchy fairly quickly.